# MongoDB query group with 'sub' group

Tags: mongodb

From a product stocks log I have created a MongoDB collection. The relevant fields are: sku, stock and date. Every time a products stock is updated there is a new entry with the total stock.

The skus are made up of two parts. A parent part, say 'A' and a variant or child part, say '1', '2', '3', etc.. So a sku might look like this: 'A2'.

I can query for a single products stock, grouped by day, with this query:

```
    [{
        $match: {
            sku: 'A2'
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                year: {$year: '$date'}, 
                day: {$dayOfYear: '$date'}
            },
            stock: {
                $min: '$stock'
            },
            date: {
                $first: '$date'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            date: 1
        }
    }]
```

Note: I want the minimum stock for each day.

But I need to query for all variations (minimum) stocks added up. I can change the $match object to:

```
    [{
        $match: {
            sku: /^A/
        }
    }
```

How do I create a 'sub' group in the $group stage?

EDIT:

The data looks like this:

```
{
    sku: 'A1',
    date: '2015-01-01',
    stock: 15
}

{
    sku: 'A1',
    date: '2015-01-01',
    stock: 14
}

{
    sku: 'A2',
    date: '2015-01-01',
    stock: 20
}
```

Two stocks for 'A1' and one for 'A2' on a single day. My query (all skus grouped by day) would give me stock 14 as a result ($min of the 3 values). But I want the result to be 34. 20 (min for A2) plus 14 (min for A1)

Comment: Description of the document is best understood with code itself, can you show some sample documents and what your expected output is?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the sku to the _id field in the group phase it will aggregate on that as well, i.e. group per sku, year & day.

```
db.stocks.aggregate(
[
  {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            sku: '$sku',
            year: {$year: '$date'}, 
            day: {$dayOfYear: '$date'}
        },
        stock: {
            $min: '$stock'
        },
        date: {
            $first: '$date'
        }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
        date: 1
    }
  }]
)
```